# React instantSearch | Algolia

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, algolia, react-instantsearch

I'm trying to use the **searchBox** of **react instantSearch** and use the **Hits** to show the data in a separated component but it is not working.

To simplify my idea I have a component called `Searching navbar` and another one called `Items container`.

I want to use the search box from the `Searching navbar` and show the data in the `Items container`

Is it possible to do it like this or do I have to stick with one component ?d

```
`

<InstantSearch indexName="wp_searchable_posts" searchClient={searchClient} searchState={this.state.searchTerm || {
    query: 'admissions' }} onSearchStateChange={this.onSearchStateChange}>
    <Grid container spacing={24}>
        <Grid item s={12}>
            <SearchBox autofocus={true} />
            <Stats />
            <InfiniteHits hitComponent={Hit} />
        </Grid>
        {/* TODO: Align these more precisely */}
        {/* <Grid item s={3} style={{ alignSelf: 'center', marginTop: 4 }}>
            <HierarchicalMenu attributes={[ 'post_type_label' , 'taxonomies_hierarchical.faculty-departments.lvl0' ]}
                limit={50} rootPath={null} separator=" > " showMore={false} showMoreLimit={20} showParentLevel /> */}
            {/* </Grid> */}
    </Grid>
</InstantSearch>`
```

This is the code i'm using to show the search box with the results.

Comment: Any code about what you have achieved?

Comment: @keikai i just added a piece from the code where i call the instantSearch